# How to extract tgz file using java

Tags: java

Is there any java code which extracts 'tgz' file.
I searched a lot but didn't get any. So i first converted it into tar file and then i used code to extract tar file.
But my tar file contains xml, sh and tgz files so it is getting stucked.
code is:

```
public class test1 {


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  File file = new File("D:\\Delta\\Interactive\\qml_windows\\development\\onemedia\\");

     final List<File> untaredFiles = new LinkedList<File>();
        final InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\onemedia\\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar"); 
        final TarArchiveInputStream debInputStream = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", is);
        TarArchiveEntry entry = null; 
        while ((entry = (TarArchiveEntry)debInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            final File outputFile = new File(file, entry.getName());
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                    if (!outputFile.mkdirs()) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Couldn't create directory %s.", outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                final OutputStream outputFileStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile); 
                IOUtils.copy(debInputStream, outputFileStream);
                outputFileStream.close();
            }
            untaredFiles.add(outputFile);
        }
        debInputStream.close(); 


 }

}
```

This code extracts tar file.
Still i am getting error as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\onemedia\onemedia_4\adload.tgz (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with the fact that your archive contains xml, sh and tgz files.

Comment: "But my tar file contains xml, sh and tgz files so it is getting stucked" - that's a non-sequitur.

Comment: Then what might be the prb

Comment: I would say the problem is that the system cannot find the path specified for `D:\onemedia\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar\onemedia_4\adload.tgz`, which is why the message says "D:\onemedia\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar\onemedia_4\adload.tgz (The system cannot find the path specified)"

Comment: But i checked... this path is right

Comment: Is `D:\onemedia\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar` a folder?

Comment: D:\onemedia\ is a folder and onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar is a file

Comment: @Dimple So no, `D:\onemedia\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar` is not a folder. Because `D:\onemedia\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar` is not a folder, `D:\onemedia\onemedia-dal-504-v4.tar\onemedia_4\adload.tgz` can't possibly exist on the file system (because it would have to be inside something that is not a folder).

Comment: Pls see the edited code. Now i gave directly the path for tar file. Still its showing error